# Convert PUCHAR to PWCHAR in Minifilter

Tags: windows, memory, wdk, windows-kernel, minifilter

Before i use Minifilter,i was change PUCHAR to char* and then use GetWC to change this into wchar_t Like:

```
wchar_t* GetWC(const char* c)
{
    long cSize = strlen(c) + 1;
    wchar_t* wc = ExAllocatePool(POOL_FLAG_NON_PAGED, cSize);
    if (!wc)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    mbstowcs(wc, c, cSize);
    return wc;
}
wchar_t* pathwchart = GetWC((char*)ntpath);
```

but now I use Minifilter,and when i use ExAllocatePool in the CallBacks of Minifilter,it will back a SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION 0X3B error in blue screen,so how can i Convert PUCHAR to PWCHAR in Minifilter.

Comment: `POOL_FLAG_NON_PAGED` this is flag from[`POOL_FLAGS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/pool_flags) and used in **another** api - [`ExAllocatePool2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-exallocatepool2). this is invalid parameter for [`POOL_TYPE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ne-wdm-_pool_type) used in [`ExAllocatePool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-exallocatepool) and use nonapaged pool wrong here in all case

Comment: and your `cSize` is too small (always) for `wchar_t` string

Comment: Oh thank u,i juse use ```wchar_t* imgct = ExAllocatePool2(POOL_FLAG_PAGED, strlen(imagename) + 1, "CAMT");```and solve the question

Answer (score 0):

```
wchar_t* GetWC(const char* c) {
    long cSize = strlen(c) + 1;
    wchar_t* wc = ExAllocatePool2(POOL_FLAG_PAGED, cSize,"TAGHERE");
    if (!wc)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    mbstowcs(wc, c, cSize);
    return wc; }
```

just change the ExAllocatePool to ExAllocatePool2 and page flag and solve the question

Comment: code is wrong anyway, *cSize = strlen(c) + 1;* is too small. for what you need `ExAllocatePool2` ?

Comment: Do you mean the memory I applied for is too small?and i change my code to ```long cSize = (strlen(c) + 1) * 4;```//now i *sizeof(wchar_t) is batter?or maybe can I use other methods to replace this is better

Comment: `sizeof(wchar_t)==2`, not 4. more correct call `RtlMultiByteToUnicodeSize`